# iOS SocketRocket and Long-Polling

Tags: ios, websocket, long-polling, socketrocket

Has anyone used SocketRocket in a scenario where they also needed to fallback to long-polling? If so does SocketRocket have any support for this scenario? Do you have any details or ideas for this kind of situation from the native iOS client side?